# Rabbit mq message duplication

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amazon-sqs

I have a question about stability on rabbitmq delivery.

[The rabbit mq official homepage](https://www.rabbitmq.com/reliability.html) says that acknowledgments call guarantees delivery at least once.

Can a producer-generated message be delivered more than once? (
I wonder if consumer can do duplicate work on the same message.)

I don`t speak English well. The contents may be strange. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can a producer-generated message be delivered more than once

Yes. If a consumer dies without sending an ack, RabbitMQ will re-queue unAcked messages sent to it. These messages will be redelivered to other consumers with a redelivered flag in its properties.

Comment: If the consumer correctly sends an ack, Do not i get duplicate messages anymore ??

Comment: Yes. But nothing is impossible, you should also guarantee the idempotence of message consume in your code.